# Implement Compose Bottom Navigation using Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I followed the compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) to create a bottom navigation bar by creating such a sealed class

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String, val icon: ImageVector) {
    object ScreenA: Screen("screenA", "ScreenA", Icons.Default.AccountBox)
    object ScreenB: Screen("screenB", "ScreenB", Icons.Default.ThumbUp
}
```

with something such as the following screen, simply containing a Text item.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA() {
    Text(text = "This is ScreenA",
        style = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 36.sp),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
}
```

and have also implemented the `Scaffold, BottomNavigation, and NavHost` exactly like in the docs and everything is working just fine.

Let´s say I now want to have one of the screens with a whole bunch of data displayed in a list with all sorts of business logic methods which would need a Fragment, ViewModel, Repository, and so on.
What would be the correct approach be? Can I still create the fragments and somehow pass them to the sealed class or should we forget about fragments and make everything composable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are following the documentation you need to forget about Fragments. Documentations suggests that view models per screen will be instantiated when the composable function is called/navigated to. The viewmodel will live while the composeable is not disposed. This is also motivated by single activity approach.

```
@Inject  lateinit var factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory


@Composable
fun Profile(profileViewModel = viewModel(factory),
    userId: String,
    navigateToFriendProfile: (friendUserId: String) -> Unit) {
  
}
```

This can be seen in compose samples [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/home/CraneHome.kt#L99).

---

If you want to mix both, you can omit using `navigation-compose`, and roll with navigation component and use `Fragment` and only use composable for fragment UI.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfileFragment: BaseFragment() {

    private val profileViewModel by viewModels<ProfileViewModel>(viewModelFactory)
    private val profileFragmentArgs by navArg<ProfileFragmentArgs>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
               Profile(profileViewModel = profileViewModel, id = profileFragmentArgs.id, navigateToFriendProfile = { findNavController().navigate(...)  })  
            }
        }
    }
```